# Is it possible to make a operating system by getting a linux kernel to run java code?

Tags: java, c, assembly, operating-system

I have always gotten the idea of getting a kernel to run java code, so the back end is made on c and assembly and the front end is made on java? If so, where can I find the Linux kernel source code?

Comment: "where can I find the Linux kernel source code?" - [kernel.org](https://kernel.org/).

Comment: thanks, but is it possible?

Comment: If you need to ask if it is possible, it means you probably need to spend months to years learning C and kernel programming. Because of course it is possible, JVM is pure software.

Comment: This is actually a really good idea for making a operating system and because linux is open source, I can just edit ~/.bashrc and add some lines of code that downloads jre or jdk executes some java code.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to run Java code from within the kernel, that would end you having to implement a JVM embedded like a module, or launch a java program from within a driver, by making the driver depend on the JVM. That seems not a great idea, as it usually would end with a very fragile system in terms of dependencies, a very heavy image, and a mix of responsibilities in the kernel space.

You're probably mistaking the kernel space, the init sequence and the user space. From your description "so the back end is made on c and assembly and the front end is made on java?" it seems more likely that you want to run some java programs as SysVInit / systemd services that are providing the user with an interface to the OS, not as part of the Kernel.

When done so, the init manager will cascade-run all necessary services from the distribution, giving them appropriate resources and permissions, after the kernel initializes itself, filesystems, virtual memory,... and the hardware.

Running a java program as a systemd service is very easy (and from SysVInit, too). From a simple unit service,

```
[Unit]
Description=Hello Service -- A Service.
# Before and after directives go in this section. 
# Example for waiting for the network to start the service:
# After=network.target

[Service]
User=user
Group=group
ExecStart=/path/to/start.sh
ExecStop=/path/to/stop.sh
Type=forking

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

you only need to set the appropriate users and groups, according to the privileges of your software, and launch your Java program from `start.sh` and stop it from `stop.sh`, where you can set your java command line, environment variables and checks.

Make sure you start your Java program with nohup, to avoid interfering with systemd and its logs:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
nohup java -cp /opt/hello:/opt/hello/* com.package.hello.Start > /tmp/hello.out 2>&1 &
```

Probably you would like to check SysVInit as it usually is lighter, but I hope this answer gives you some ideas.